# Android Studio Launcher icon is black

Tags: android, android-studio, icons, app-launcher

I made an image in photoshop for my application, but when I go to add a new `Image Asset`, the icon is black. Here is an example

[image]

In the previous version from Android Studio launcher icons had the real color. Is it a bug?

Answer (score 0):

It could be the format of the image, have you looked at the [Android Api](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_launcher.html) and made sure it meets the specs?

Comment: It was a bit of a longshot suggestion, I know that sometimes Android Studio has strange issues with displaying things correctly on screen. Have you tried using that icon, and running the app on an actual device? Sometimes it will display perfectly fine on real hardware, but not in Android Studio...

Comment: After looking up version 2.2, it might have some issues. Preview 3 launched less than a week ago, and it integrated a few image support changes. [This has some info on that front.](http://tools.android.com/recent)

Comment: If not, then I am officially out of ideas. Sorry! I'll stay subscribed to this thread, let me know if you find a solution.

Comment: @VassilisPallas did you find solution for this? I'm facing similar issue for Preview 3.

Comment: Unfortunately no. I had an older version from Android Studio in my old desktop, so I made the icons from there...I hope that on the new update the problem will be solved