# Android App iCon configuration issue - black & white

Tags: android, imageicon, mobile-application

I'm trying to setup icon for android app but when I click the iCon setup and select Launcher Icons, selected image, even ic_launcher.png is showing as black & white. Am I missing any setting here?

[image: iCon Launcher - Image Asset]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37822615/24352383

Comment: @sJy I saw that question but no solution so had created this question.

Comment: Its an issue with Android Studio.

Comment: Actually it's problem with using Android Studio Preview versus stable version which is ready for production app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting the solution or issue causing this problem. I was using Android Studio Preview and that was the issue. Preview is not ready for production app, it's like beta version. I reverted to the stable version of the app and it's working perfectly for icons. Attached is sample image for Android Studio 2.1.2[image]